# Resolving fingerprint scanner registration in flexcodesdk

Tags: vb.net, fingerprint

I am trying to develop an application on class attendance using fingerprint. Through rigorous research, I found out that I can use 'flexcodesdk' for my Vb.net program.

But the issue is that for every fingerprint scanner (Digitalpersona)  there is needed to register it on flexcodesdk site to get series of API keys. What am I going to do about this issue because once I change the fingerprint scanner of similar product, it will complain of registration invalid.

Many developer develop applications an any body can use different scanner regardless of the serial number.

Help me out gurus in the house.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that their FAQ states that each license is tied to a specific device.

> How many devices that can be used in one FlexCode SDK license ?
>
> Only the device that you submitted the registration number.

This means that each new device needs to be registered into their system in order to provide you with a new license for their SDK.
This seems quite a restricting model.

Perhaps you might want to consider the free and open source c# implementation at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97590/A-Framework-in-C-for-Fingerprint-Verification

I have successfully created multiple applications using this framework.

Comment: I am very grateful for your advice. I will try that. Thanks so much. I will contact you, please, whenever I ran into a problem. once again, I am very grateful.

Comment: Hello @xFx,  please I being battling with the package you gave me. I couldn't find a means to interface a fingerprint hardware with any of its classes. Please help me out

Comment: @Cage, have you tried using the sample application that's included with the source code? If it also failed, then maybe your scanners require some special API?

Comment: In case it helps, I have uploaded a simple and very basic sample to [GitHub](https://github.com/morphx666/FingerprintManager)

Comment: please don't regard me being lazy. Forgive me for disturbing you. I have downloaded the package, follow the instructions and arrive at every screenshots successfully. All their samples, especially the last one, gave room to upload already stored fingerprints not to load the from a fingerprint hardware scanner. Please, if am not rude for requesting for this, could you show me the where it's embedded in the package? Or give me another working samples. Please am begging. It's a final year project.